# Very elusive Metal issue with 'nextDrawable'

Tags: metal, metalkit

I have a setup of four 1920x1080 `MTKView` instances as subviews of an `NSWindow` on a 3840x2160 monitor as a debugging configuration.  Imagine my four views numbered as quadrants ("1" in upper-right, then going counter-clockwise).  There are four videos playing on these views. Their `CVPixelBuffers` are captured from each respective `AVPlayer`, via a dedicated `CVDisplayLink` render loop for each.  Each `MTKView` is configured for manual drawing by these same four `CVDisplayLink` callbacks.  The `MTKView` `draw` call therein is inside an `@autoreleasepool`.

All this works quite well about 95% of the time -- with about 75% GPU memory usage and about 20% GPU processing on a Radeon R9 M395, iMac 5k Late 2015 w/Fusion Drive.  A Metal Trace in Xcode has all my GPU rendering taking not more than 5ms per frame.

**I'm trying to track down why some of my videos stutter about 5% of the time.**
A GPU Frame capture is giving me a clue, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

In each `MTKView` `drawRect` call, I do 4 passes of kernel shader work on a texture that I've allocated and up to two incoming `CVPixelBuffer` textures  (ie. for fades from one video to the next).  I don't request or touch the `currentRenderPassDescriptor` in there.

Immediately following these batches of `MTLComputeCommandEncoder` work, I have one final pass with a `MTLRenderCommandEncoder` and a set of vertices with the final compute texture result as input:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.inflightSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [metalCommandQueue commandBuffer];

    <do 4 passes of compute work>

    // ********* The next line is where WARNINGS (see below) occur ***********
    MTLRenderPassDescriptor *renderPassDescriptor = self.currentRenderPassDescriptor;

    id<MTLDrawable> currentDrawable = nil;
    if (renderPassDescriptor) {
       currentDrawable = self.currentDrawable;
       [self doVertexWork:inputTexture
          onCommandBuffer:commandBuffer
           withDescriptor:renderPassDescriptor];
    }

    [commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer) {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.inflightSemaphore);
    }];

    if (currentDrawable)
        [commandBuffer presentDrawable:currentDrawable];
    [commandBuffer commit];

    commandBuffer=nil;
}
```

If I do a GPU frame capture, I note a frame rate of 120fps, 4 draw calls, 4 command buffers, and 4 render encoders.  However, I get a total of 7 warnings on the line indicated:

- `CAMetalLayer nextDrawable Called Early` (once)
- `CAMetalLayer nextDrawable was Called Unnecessarily` (three times)
- `Command Buffer was not Enqueued and Committed in this Frame` (three times -- the command buffers on quadrants 1,3,4)

BTW, a note about calling early provided by Xcode: `"Your application called CAMetalLayer nextDrawable earlier than needed.  This may block execution until a CAMetalDrawable is available.  Delay the call to nextDrawable until the drawing is needed for encoding".`

I notice in the docs that the blocked execution occurs for one second, which matches the timing of the stutter I'm occasionally seeing (ie. updates every 1 second or so).

On the `endEncoding` call when I'm doing my vertex work, I get a `"CAMetalDrawable used from Earlier Frame"` warning (three times, with textures from quadrants 1,2,4 only).

Interesting side note: when the frame capture paused things, the image from quadrant 3 was duplicated in quadrant 2, and quadrant two's image was not visible.

**I can't really figure out what my issue is as I'm following the techniques used by all the examples I've seen out there.**

**Any help would be appreciated.**

---

**UPDATE #1**

Based on [Ken-Thomases](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312143/ken-thomases) helpful comments, I inserted the following line immediately after the creation of the command buffer in the draw call:

```
[metalCommandQueue insertDebugCaptureBoundary];
```

This resolved almost all of the purported issues, but I'm still seeing the 1-second stutters occasionally.  The only remaining issue is a consistent `CAMetalLayer nextDrawable was Called Unnecessarily` with a comment that "your application called `CAMetalLayer nextDrawable` but did not use the returned `CAMetalDrawable` during the frame".  This occurs irrespective of whether the stutter is occurring.

Near as I can tell, this `nextDrawable` call is stalling things occasionally for me.

---

Comment: I think the GPU frame debugger's warning are not related to the cause of the stutter. The issue with the warnings is the definition of a frame when you've got four completely independent rendering cycles going simultaneously. Xcode can't track them independently. It considers the `-presentDrawable:` calls the frame boundaries. See the docs for [`-[MTLCommandQueue insertDebugCaptureBoundary]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandqueue/1508692-insertdebugcaptureboundary). Probably Instruments will do a better job here.

Comment: You could maybe use separate command queues, separate per-queue `MTLCaptureScope`s, and `MTLCaptureManager` to help Xcode cope better with the independent rendering loops.

Comment: I just tried that.... using `newCaptureScopeWithCommandQueue` on separate queues concurrently is quite useless;  If I attempt this on the 4 separate command queues with disparate `MTLCaptureScope` instances I get an error `MTLCaptureManager: startCaptureWithScope attempted while a capture is active`.  LOL.

Comment: Update #1 above... using the deprecated `insertDebugCaptureBoundary` instead.

Comment: Well, with `MTLCaptureManager`, you would either capture only one of the rendering loops at at time (programmatically), or you would long-press the capture button in Xcode to select one scope to capture. I was not suggesting you use `-insertDebugCaptureBoundary` because it doesn't solve the problem of multiple frames going at a time. I still think that Instruments is probably the best tool for this. The GPU frame capture is not so helpful for finding the cause of stalls, I don't think.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Doing the long click and picking a specific (laggy) command queue to capture causes Xcode 9.4.1 to crash about 1/3 of the time ;-).  BTW, the Metal Trace command tools may be the best way to debug this, but it seems the timing differences with the tracing turned on prevent my issue from occurring.

Comment: Do you have multiple displays attached? I have determined when multiple displays are attached, nextDrawable calls will exceed 16.67ms for short periods, causing stuttering. Using instruments, it is evident that display sync events for each display are not aligned. My hypothesis is the CVDisplayLink, CAMetalLayer and CGDisplay presenting the view are not congruent.

Comment: Yes, I use the iMac for the main display and then all these MTKViews are on a separate display.  My solution was to relegate each MTKView to its own window on the external display rather than having multiple views per window; the drawable quota of three seems to be per window, not per MTKView.